# How can I resolve dependencies when cross-compiling in Scala with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to build a 2.11 and 2.12 version of my project, so I have something like this in my Build.scala file:

```
val scalaVer12 = "2.12.1"
val scalaVer = "2.11.8"

lazy val basicSettings = Seq(
    // lots of other settings
    scalaVersion                := scalaVer
)
```

The fly in the soup is I have a dependency on scala reflection, which is based on the scala version.  Before I did this:

```
val scala_reflect   = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % Build.scalaVer
```

How can I modify this dependency line so that sbt will use either the 2.11 or 2.12 dependency based upon the version it's currently building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lazy val bla = project in file("bla")
 .settings(
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
   )
 )
```

Never alias dependencies like that, it's clean to have an object to store version numbers, but not more, it's just a smell, especially since deps are often Scala version dependent and you can apply all sorts of rules to them.